# How to normalize data taken from Apple Watch accelerometer?

Tags: normalization, apple-watch, watchos

I have triaxial data (X, Y, and Z) collected from the accelerometer of an Apple Watch, and from these data I want to conduct some analysis, such as gait analysis, physical activity, etc.

I have observed that my data-X, data-Y and data-Z are in different scales, and I have the following questions:

1. Is suitable to conduct a normalization process on my data before conducting a gait analysis?
2. If it is the case, What is the proper way to perform a normalization on accelerometer data?

Comment: Why don't you use HealthKit instead? Like steps and activity summary? I mean what the reason is to analyze this because Apple is already doing this? Maybe also add to you question which watchOS you're developing on.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I will look into HealthKit. Yes, I want a summary of steps, distance, activity, but I also want to compute some type of Equilibreum score, sway, tremor, etc, and I don't know if HealthKit includes metrics like these. As far as I know, HealthKit does not include this type of metric, that is the main reason  that I finally should work with raw data taken from acelerometer. Do you have any suggestion on how to compute metrics like Equilibreum, sway, tremor, etc?